# Check if the last digit of a string is odd or even c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem to get the last digit from a string.

```
//read data from MS Excel
while (reader.Read())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Id"].Value = reader[0].ToString();
   dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Name"].Value = reader[1].ToString();
   dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["DateOfBirth"].Value = reader[2].ToString();
}

// then I want to save the data into database from excel
// so i want to write code to check the id
// for example : id = "030711026098"
while (reader.Read())
{
    id = reader[0].ToString();
    name = reader[1].ToString();
    dob = reader[2].ToString();
    gender = ??
    // Gender will be decided based on the id
    // if the last digit is odd, then gender = male
    // if the last digit is even, then gender = female
}
// do the insert
```

Comment: Of course that's a thing: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Gender](https://gist.github.com/garbados/f82604ea639e0e47bf44).

Comment: Do you mean last char int value or last char ASCII value? What about strings like this: "123abc"? Do you assume that last char is from range 0...9?

Comment: Last char mean whole number is even or odd. Why explicitly extract last char?

Comment: @CodeCaster I believe OP is checking an Identification Card number to determine gender which is used in certain countries. The first six digits are `YYMMDD`, next two digits are `Code for Place of Birth` and the last four are random digits which uses even and odd to determine gender.

Comment: @active92 yeahhhh that's true.. thank u for your explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 id = "030711026098";

// get last char of the string 
char lastChar = id.substr(id.length - 1);
// convert last number to an integer 
int number = Convert.ToInt32(lastChar);
// this returns true if number is odd
bool isOdd = return number % 2 != 0;

if(isOdd)
 //female
else 
 //male
```

Or one line:

```
 string gender = Convert.ToInt32(id.Substring(id.Length - 1)) % 2 != 0 ? "female" : "male";
```

Comment: I'm using that one line code and it working.. thank u :) `string gender = Convert.ToInt32(id.Substring(id.Length - 1)) % 2 != 0 ? "Male" : "Female";`

Comment: @Zeera hopefully you learn ternary operator instead of just using it blindly because you could've just used `string gender = Convert.ToInt64(temp) % 2 != 0 ? "female" : "male";` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
String id = "030711026098"
char last = id[id.Length-1];
if(Convert.ToInt32(last) % 2 ==0)
//female
else 
//male
```

Get the last character of string using length of string. Convert it to an integer and check if it is divisible by 2. If it is divisible then it's even and hence male else female.

Answer (score 0):

```
String id = "030711026098";
bool isLastCharOdd = (Convert.ToInt32(id[id.Length-1])) % 2 != 0;
if(isLastCharOdd)
   //male
else
   //female
```

Comment: It lake of some explanation. With that, it can become a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I've converted the whole thing into int64 since the length is always fix.

```
 string temp = "030711026099";
 long i = Convert.ToInt64(temp);
 if (i % 2 == 0)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Female");
 }
 else
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Male");
 }
```

Comment: tq for answering.. I'm getting the id from `reader[0].ToString();` and the error is _Input string was not in a correct format_ at this line `long i = Convert.ToInt64(temp)`

Comment: I guess maybe because I have null value for certain rows in id column. That's why it say _Input string was not in a correct format_ I delete the empty rows and it working :) TQ